# Matplotlib subplot2grid packing with axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, subplot

Any help in getting the subplot2grid and the axes labels to work nicely together will be so much appreciated. As you can see in the picture attached some of the axes labels overlap the surface of the neighbouring subplots.
Attached some code as well in case it helps.

```
def init_plot(self):

    self.f0 = plt.figure(num = 0, figsize = (12, 8))#, dpi = 100)
    self.f0.suptitle("CFM diffusion", fontsize=12)
    self.ax01 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 0))
    self.ax02 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 1))
    self.ax03 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 0))
    self.ax04 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 1))
    self.ax05 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 2))
    self.ax06 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 2))


    self.ax01.set_ylim((300, 0))
    self.ax02.set_ylim((300,0))
    self.ax03.set_ylim((230, 250))
    self.ax04.set_ylim((0.08, 0.22))
    self.ax02.set_xlim((230, 250))
    self.ax03.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax04.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax05.set_ylim((300,0))
    self.ax05.set_xlim((0, 0.125))
    self.ax06.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax06.set_ylim((0.08, 0.125))

    self.ax01.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax01.set_xlabel(r"Density [$\mathrm{kgm}^{-3}$]")
    self.ax02.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax02.set_xlabel(r"Temperature [K]")
    self.ax03.set_ylabel(r"Temperature Forcing [K]")
    self.ax03.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")
    self.ax04.set_ylabel(r"Accumulation Forcing [$\mathrm{my}^{-1}$ ice eq.]")
    self.ax04.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")
    self.ax05.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax05.set_xlabel(r"Diffusion Length [m]")
    self.ax06.set_ylabel(r"$\sigma'_{18}$ [m]")
    self.ax06.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")

    # self.ax01.set_title('Density profile')
    # self.ax02.set_title('Temp. profile')
    # self.ax03.set_title('Temperature Forcing')
    # self.ax04.set_title('Accum Forcing')
    # self.ax05.set_title('Diffusion Length')
    # self.ax06.set_title('Diffusion Length at CO')

    self.hlp011 = self.ax01.plot(self.rho_hl*1000, self.z_hl, "r--")
    self.p011, = self.ax01.plot(self.rho[0][1:], self.z[0][1:],'b-')
    self.p012, = self.ax02.plot(self.temperature[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'k-')
    self.p021, = self.ax03.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.climate[0,2],'k-')
    self.p022, = self.ax04.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.climate[0,1], 'k-')
    print(self.climate[0,1])
    self.p023, = self.ax05.plot(self.iso_sigmaD[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'r-')
    self.p024, = self.ax05.plot(self.iso_sigma18[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'b-')
    self.iso_sigma18_co = np.array((self.iso_sigma18[0][1:][self.rho[0][1:]>804.3][0],))
    self.p025, = self.ax06.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.iso_sigma18_co[0], 'b-')

    return
```

Best
Vas[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout) with guide [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

In your code just add this line after creating `self.f0`:

```
self.f0.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer here:
self.f0.tight_layout() takes care of things with some padding to account for the title on top.

```
class CfmPlotter():

def __init__(self, fpath = None):


    hl_inst = herron_lang.HL(temp = -40.0+273.15, accu= 0.0917, rho_o=350.)

    self.z_hl, self.rho_hl = hl_inst(np.arange(0,400, 0.01))
    # fpath = "./DO_results/DO_tests_vary_tr_time/cfm_DO_trtime_1500/Goujon_DO_trtime_1500.hdf5"
    self.fpath = fpath
    f = h5py.File(fpath)
    self.fs = os.path.split(fpath)[1]
    print f.keys()
    self.z = f["depth"][:]
    self.rho = f["density"][:]
    self.temperature = f["temperature"][:]
    self.age = f["age"][:]
    self.climate = f["Modelclimate"][:]
    self.iso_sigmaD = f["iso_sigmaD"][:]
    self.iso_sigma18 = f["iso_sigma18"][:]
    self.iso_sigma17 = f["iso_sigma17"][:]
    self.model_time = np.array(([a[0] for a in self.z[:]]))

    f.close()
    return


def init_plot(self):

    self.f0 = plt.figure(num = 0, figsize = (10, 6))#, dpi = 100)
    self.f0.tight_layout(pad = 2.8)
    self.f0.suptitle("CFM diffusion", fontsize=12)
    self.ax01 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 0))
    self.ax02 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 1))
    self.ax03 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 0))
    self.ax04 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 1))
    self.ax05 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (0, 2))
    self.ax06 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 3), (1, 2))


    self.ax01.set_ylim((300, 0))
    self.ax02.set_ylim((300,0))
    self.ax03.set_ylim((230, 250))
    self.ax04.set_ylim((0.08, 0.22))
    self.ax02.set_xlim((230, 250))
    self.ax03.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax04.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax05.set_ylim((300,0))
    self.ax05.set_xlim((0, 0.125))
    self.ax06.set_xlim((self.model_time[0], self.model_time[-1]))
    self.ax06.set_ylim((0.08, 0.125))

    self.ax01.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax01.set_xlabel(r"Density [$\mathrm{kgm}^{-3}$]")
    self.ax02.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax02.set_xlabel(r"Temperature [K]")
    self.ax03.set_ylabel(r"Temperature Forcing [K]")
    self.ax03.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")
    self.ax04.set_ylabel(r"Accumulation Forcing [$\mathrm{my}^{-1}$ ice eq.]")
    self.ax04.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")
    self.ax05.set_ylabel(r"Depth [m]")
    self.ax05.set_xlabel(r"Diffusion Length [m]")
    self.ax06.set_ylabel(r"$\sigma'_{18}$ [m]")
    self.ax06.set_xlabel(r"Model Time [y]")

    # self.ax01.set_title('Density profile')
    # self.ax02.set_title('Temp. profile')
    # self.ax03.set_title('Temperature Forcing')
    # self.ax04.set_title('Accum Forcing')
    # self.ax05.set_title('Diffusion Length')
    # self.ax06.set_title('Diffusion Length at CO')

    self.hlp011 = self.ax01.plot(self.rho_hl*1000, self.z_hl, "r--")
    self.p011, = self.ax01.plot(self.rho[0][1:], self.z[0][1:],'b-')
    self.p012, = self.ax02.plot(self.temperature[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'k-')
    self.p021, = self.ax03.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.climate[0,2],'k-')
    self.p022, = self.ax04.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.climate[0,1], 'k-')
    print(self.climate[0,1])
    self.p023, = self.ax05.plot(self.iso_sigmaD[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'r-')
    self.p024, = self.ax05.plot(self.iso_sigma18[0][1:], self.z[0][1:], 'b-')
    self.iso_sigma18_co = np.array((self.iso_sigma18[0][1:][self.rho[0][1:]>804.3][0],))
    self.p025, = self.ax06.plot(self.climate[0,0], self.iso_sigma18_co[0], 'b-')

    return
```

[image: final plot]